# is this a valid array for arduino and C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I would like to create several array's using the following naming convention

```
const int zone2[] = {11};
const int zone3[] = {12,13};
const int zone4[] = {14};
```

then I would like to create a loop and check get the values of the array I am doing the following.

```
// read the state of the pushbutton value:
byte myInput =2;

//Outer loop checks the state of the Input Pins
//Inner loop iterates through corresponding array and pulls pins high or low depending on ButtonState

for (myInput = 2;myInput<5; myInput++) {
    buttonState = digitalRead(myInput);

    int ArrayCount;

    String zoneChk = "zone" + String(myInput);
    ArrayCount = sizeof(zoneChk) / sizeof( int ) ; // sizeof( int ) is the newpart
    int arrayPosition;

    for (arrayPosition = 0;arrayPosition < ArrayCount ; arrayPosition++) {
        if (buttonState == HIGH) {     
            // turn LED on:    
            digitalWrite(zoneChk[arrayPosition], HIGH);  
        } 
        else {
            // turn LED off:
            digitalWrite(zoneChk[arrayPosition], LOW);
        }
    } 
}
```

I have been told the array is invalid for C++ arduino, I am not so sure and just learning as I go.  I am looking to control some house lights the Zones are effectively rooms and the contents of the array the different lights within the room.  I have called them Zones'x' so I can reducr the code need to check the switches for each room.

thanks

Comment: No idea of special arduino stuff, but the arrays look fine.

Comment: Just a guess but `sizeof(zoneChk)` is giving you the size of the `String` type not the string buffer it manages. See if `String` as a `size` or `length` member function.

Comment: You can't construct a variable name at runtime. Assigning a specific string to a `String` variable doesn't make that variable magically refer to a different variable named like the string assigned.

Comment: molbdnilo I am a little confused what part are you referring to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> String zoneChk = "zone" + String(myInput);
> ArrayCount = sizeof(zoneChk) / sizeof( int ) ; // sizeof( int ) is the newpart
> ```

Nooo no no no no.

```
const int * const zones[] = {zone2, zone3, zone4};

 ...

for (int z = 0; z < 3; ++z)
{
  // access zones[z]
}
```

Also, consider null-terminating each `zoneX` (and optionally `zones`) so that you know when you've reached the end.

Comment: so then am I creating zones2[] = {11} and ArrayCount = sizeof(zones[z])/sizeof(int); sorry very new to C++ thanks

Comment: Create `zones2[] = {11, 0}` and go until you hit the 0 instead of trying to get the size (`for (arrayPosition = 0; zones[z][arrayPosition]; ++arrayPosition) {`).

Comment: I am trying to declare the arrays at the start of the project const int * zones[]={zone2};
const zone2[] = {11,0}; However I am getting the error message  error: 'zone2' was not declared in this scope
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'zone2' with no type   I have no idea whats wrong

Comment: C++ uses a single-pass compiler; the symbol has to exist before you can use it.

Comment: thanks but I have the const int * const zones[] = {zone2}; at the very start of the project.

Comment: That's nice. Where's `zone2`?

Comment: the second line, const zone2[] = {11,0};

Comment: thanks I did have it the other way round but had missed out the int part thank you

Comment: Got everything working on zone2 flick the switch and zone2 come s on three lights on working and off when flick switch again I have added a zone3 only one light should come on and all 3 light up?

Comment: Sounds like you have a new problem. Open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
String zoneChk = "zone" + String(myInput);
ArrayCount = sizeof(zoneChk) / sizeof( int ) ; // sizeof( int ) is the newpart
```

This will not allow you to access the zone2..5 variables at runtime. You are creating a "zone2" string that has nothing to do with the zone2 variable.

The code below compiles but I don't have an Arduino with me to fully test it. It will still allow you to change the size of zone2,3,4 without any modifications to the code. You will have to add more case statements (there is commented out zone5 code included) if you want more zones.

If you want it to be fully dynamic we can use a multi-dimensional array for the zones but this should be a good start for minimal code

```
for (myInput = 2;myInput<5; myInput++) {
    int buttonState = digitalRead(myInput);

    int ArrayCount;
    const int *zoneChk;

    //This is the part you will have to add to if you want more zones
    switch(myInput){
        case 2:
          ArrayCount = sizeof(zone2) / sizeof (zone2[0]);
          zoneChk = zone2;
        break;
        case 3:
          ArrayCount = sizeof(zone3) / sizeof (zone3[0]);
          zoneChk = zone3;
        break;
        case 4:
          ArrayCount = sizeof(zone4) / sizeof (zone4[0]);
          zoneChk = zone4;
        break;
        //ex. case 5
        //case 5:
        //  ArrayCount = sizeof(zone5) / sizeof (zone5[0]);
        //  zoneChk = zone5;
        //break;
    }

    int arrayPosition;

    for (arrayPosition = 0;arrayPosition < ArrayCount ; arrayPosition++) {
        if (buttonState == HIGH) {     
            // turn LED on:    
            digitalWrite(zoneChk[arrayPosition], HIGH);  
        } 
        else {
            // turn LED off:
            digitalWrite(zoneChk[arrayPosition], LOW);
        }
    } 
}
```